Are there nontrivial examples for $[A,B] \neq 0$ but $[A,f(B)] = 0$
Like the title says I'm asking if it is possible for $[A,B] \neq 0$, but that there exists a function of $B$, $f(B)$ such that $[A,f(B)] = 0$. I'm looking for nontrivial examples. A trivial example would be cases where $f(B) = 0$ or $f(B) = \mathbb{1}$, the identity.
Edits:

By f(B) I mean functions that are Taylor expansions in $B$,
$f(B) = \sum_{n} c_n B^n$.
By $A$ I don't mean any possible operator—just $A$ not identity or zero.


And $f(B)=A$ or $f(B)=A^2+2A$?

This is not clear.  Do you have any restrictions on the function?  Why not take $f(B)=A$, for example?

If waht you are saying is that you want $f(B)$ to commute with all possible matrices (of appropriate dimensions), then I think you are down to what you'd probably call trivial cases.

Sorry, this was not clear. By $f(B)$ I meant functions that are powers of B, i.e. $f(B) = \sum_n c_n B^n$. I'll update the question

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $[A, B] \neq 0$ but $[A, B^2] = 0$. Moreover, $B^2$ can be replaced by any $f(B)$ where $f$ is a polynomial s.t. $f(1) = f(-1)$.

Thanks for your answer. This of course answers my question. A follow-up. This example have the structure of $A = \sigma_x \oplus [1] $ and $B = \sigma_z \oplus [2]$, where $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_z$ are the Pauli matrices. Do you think all nontrivial examples must take a block diagonal form of trivial cases?

@A.Jahin If $B$ is diagonalizable, then sort of yes. After diagonalizing, $B$ has entries only along the diagonal, and then you can actually calculate its commutant, which would be a direct sum of full matrix algebras on each eigenspace of $B$. If $[A, B] \neq 0$, then $A$ must have some off-diagonal entry outside those matrix algebras. So the only way for $A$ to commute with $f(B)$ would be that applying $f$ collapses two eigenspaces (that $A$ is trying to swap) into one…

@A.Jahin … Effectively, there is a block (or multiple blocks) on which $B$ was not originally scalar (your restriction to just $0$ and $1$ is too restrictive, there would be obvious counterexamples if by “trivial” you just meant $0$ and $1$, so I’m interpreting it to instead meant $f(B)$ is a scalar matrix), but $f(B)$ is scalar (on that block). And the entries of $A$ originally outside the commutant of $B$ all land in those blocks on which $f(B)$ is now scalar.

@A.Jahin Though, if you allow non-diagonalizable matrices, there are (sort of) examples which are not simply blocks of trivial cases. For example,$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\0&0&0&1\1&0&0&0\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$and$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\0&1&0&0\0&0&-1&-1\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$and again with $f(B) = B^2$.

Take the function $f(B) = [A,B]$ for a fixed $A$, then there are nontrivial examples where $[A,B]\neq 0$ but $[A,f(B)] = [A,[A,B]]=0$. A simple $2\times 2$ matrix example would be
$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right) $$
A quick calculation shows that
$$  \qquad B = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{array} \right) $$
satisfies $[A,B]\neq 0$ but $[A,[A,B]]=0$.

Thanks for your answer. This doesn't answer the question since I specified $f(B)$ to be a Taylor expansion of $B$. Sorry if you answered the question before I made that clarification.
